# datepicker in jquery with date restriction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I have a function which i initialize while loading a page

```
function initializeDateTimePickerWithDateRestriction(minimumDate, maximumDate) {
if (minimumDate == null) {
    minimumDate = "1/1/1991";
}

if (maximumDate == null) {
    maximumDate = "12/31/2099";
}
alert(minimumDate);
alert(maximumDate);
$('.DatePickerWithTime').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
    stepMinute: 15,
    minDate: minimumDate,
    maxDate: maximumDate
});

$('.DatePickerWithTime').val('');
}
```

and in the document ready part i call it as

```
initializeDateTimePickerWithDateRestriction(null, new Date());
```

But on the click event i again want to initialize some new values to this textbox without refreshing th epage.

How can i do that?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.DatePickerWithTime').datetimepicker({
    ampm: true,
    timeFormat: 'h:mm TT',
    stepMinute: 15,
    minDate: minimumDate,
    maxDate: maximumDate,
    minDateTime: minimumDate,
    maxDateTime: maximumDate,
});
```

This is the solution for the question.